# .NET CORE Web API Post is null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, postman

This is the object I'm trying to bind my JSON to

```
public class MockPost
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public int CardNumber {get; set;}
    public bool isAccepted {get; set;
}
```

This is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]MockPost body)
{
    await Db.Connection.OpenAsync();
    body.Db = Db;
    await body.InsertAsync();
    return new OkObjectResult(body);
}
```

The JSON request I'm trying to send

```
POST /api/mock HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: fddea6c0-6a33-4690-a4f8-96ec31fc70ff
Host: localhost:5001
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 53
Connection: keep-alive
{
"CardNumber": "12341234",
"isAccepted": 0
}
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2019 12:34:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

and this is the error I'm getting

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at ProduktMock.Controllers.MockController.Post(MockPost body) in c:\Users\Mikkel E.R. Glerup\produktmock\Controllers\MockController.cs:line 42
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

The exepction is because my aforementioned `Post([FromBody]MockPost body` will be null. If I make the request body into `{"MockPost":{"CardNumber":"123","IsAccepted":"1"}}` the "body" will no longer be null, but the values will be 0.

So my question is how do I get the values I send with the JSON to bind properly?

EDIT:
Turns out having the correct JSON is really important the integer was put as string and the bool was also a string, where I had thought that, that didn't matter!

Comment: {"CardNumber":"123","IsAccepted":"1"} did tried like this

Comment: Did you try `{"CardNumber": 12341234,"isAccepted": false}`?

Comment: No change by changing the structure

Comment: How does that compile when `MockPost` doesn't have a `Db` property or `InsertAsync` method? That can't be the actual code you are running.

Comment: @MikkelRohdeGlerup Unrelated suggestion; you **should** start your property names with a capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when it can't deserialize the input properly. It means, your input JSON is invalid somehow.

What I would try;

```
{
  "CardNumber": 12341234,
  "isAccepted": false,
  "id": 0
}
```

You can also check what your input should look like by entering the expected object on this page: https://csharp2json.io/

Comment: body ends up being null either way

Comment: @MikkelRohdeGlerup I think CardNumber should be integer.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid.

**Integers**

```
"CardNumber": "12341234"
```

CardNumber is an int so should be

```
"CardNumber": 12341234
```

**Booleans**

```
"isAccepted": 0
```

isAccepted is a bool so it should be

```
"isAccepted": false
```